# MS Access Expression to Find Records Where the Value to the Left of a Comma is Greater than Zero

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have some records in a column that contain IDs and some of these records contain multiple IDs separated by commas. Additionally there are some records where I have ",3" and ",2" when they should simply be "3" and "2". I do not have write privileges in this DB so updating those records is not an option.

I am trying to write a query that returns records that have a comma where the value to the left of any comma in the record is greater than 0 e.g. "2,3", "2,3,12" etc but NOT ",3" or ",2".

What would this expression look like in MS Access?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be specific, if you're just looking for records that don't start with a comma, that's really simple. If you want to return records without the starting comma, that's simple too.

Comment: I want to return records without the starting comma. That is a much better way of putting it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the starting comma from the records when you return them, you can do so using a simple query:

```
SELECT IIF(MyField LIKE ",*", Right(MyField, Len(MyField)-1), MyField)
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your *original* question, you could simply use Val:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Val([YourField]) > 0
```

Comment: Ah but that returns records where they are no commas. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use:

```
select t.*
from t
where val not like ",*";
```

This doesn't handle the `0` part, but you don't give any examples in your answer.  Perhaps this answers that part:

```
select t.*
from t
where val not like ",*" and val not like "*0,*";
```